# Yii, Selenium and multiple submit buttons

Tags: ajax, firefox, selenium, yii, functional-testing

I've got a form with two submit buttons which I want to test using Selenium.

View:

```
<?php
$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id' => 'profile-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
    'action' => '',
    'clientOptions' => array(
        'validateOnSubmit' => true,
        'validateOnChange' => true,
        'validateOnType' => false,
    ),
));
?>

<input name="cancel" type="submit" value="Cancel" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Save changes" />

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Controller is nothing special, you can assume it just prints "Your profile has been saved" or "Your profile was not saved" depending on what $_POST['cancel'] it gets

Test code:

```
<?php
$this->open('/profile_form_url');
$submit_button_selector = 'css=#profile-form input[name="submit"]';
$cancel_button_selector = 'css=#profile-form input[name="cancel"]';

$this->clickAndWait($cancel_button_selector);
$this->assertTextPresent('Your profile was not saved');

$this->open('/profile_form_url');
$this->clickAndWait($submit_button_selector);
$this->assertTextPresent('Your profile has been saved');
```

The problem is that code works great in browser but not when running tests in Selenium/Firefox. When running tests, it "sees" the first button only (Cancel), clicking "Save changes" has the same effect. If you place Save changes button first, it will not "see" Cancel button.

If you turn enableAjaxValidation off, it works both in browser and Selenium, but I'd like to have a more elegant solution of course. Like for example turning off the AJAX validation on clicking on Cancel.

No, the problem doesn't depend on which locator you use for buttons (xpath, css, id).

Comment: Have you tried adding ids to the buttons and using these as the selectors?

Comment: Yes (see the last sentence).

Comment: Did you try to slow down the Selenium steps with the setSpeed() function?

Comment: No, but just tried it - it doesn't affect the problem. Anyway, thanks for the hint, it might be useful elsewhere.

Comment: What version of Selenium, your PHP bindings and Firefox?

Comment: Selenium 2.25.0, php 5.3.5, PHPUnit_Selenium 1.2.10, firefox 20.0

Answer (score 1):

`clickAndWait()` calls `waitForPageToLoad()` - ajax form validation will generally not trigger this event (unless a page loads), so your test will never complete; this is probably why if you turn ajax validation off it works.

You might want to look at the other options selenium provides ([this is an old link to the free phpunit pocket guide](http://docs.tadiavo.com/phpunit/www.phpunit.de/pocket_guide/3.1/en/selenium.html) that describes some other options - it's based on phpunit 3.1 though) such as using `click()` and then using `waitForCondition()` with some javascript to run and return true if the new text is displayed.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not the case. clickAndWait() triggers ajax validation, which in its turn triggers form submit, so this part works fine. click() - waitForCondition() does not work because the form IS actually submitted and the page loads. The problem is that submit comes with incorrect submit button value. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.